# Can't create folder in my Android Emulator

Tags: java, android

Here is the Java code:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator + "filename");
    if(file.exists())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Boolean durum = file.mkdir();
        if(durum)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "nope, doesn't work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I added *"uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"* to Android Manifest. I couldn't add XML because it shows weirdly here.

So, I'm using Android Studio 2.2 and its own emulator. But it doesn't create any directories.

When I tried with my Samsung S4 (Android 5.0.1), it successfully creates the file but not in the SDCARD, in the device's storage.

What's happening here?

Comment: Android 6?......

Comment: `But it doesn't create any files.` ?? Files? mkdir() is for directories.

Comment: @greenapps, sorry i meant directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android >=api 23, doesn't work with manifest permmisions, try reading [this](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal) article. Also, try it in a physical device(not an emulator), if you want to run it on emulator include an sd card on it.

*The question is possible a duplicate!*

Comment: oh frak! sorry. i figured it out. so it turns out, my api was 24. but i don't know how but i was assuming that i was working with api 20. late hours!

Comment: If you need it check my implementation [here](https://github.com/amoraitis/TEDxAUEB2017.DROID/blob/master/TEDxAUEB2017/app/src/main/java/com/tedxaueb/tedxaueb2017/LoginActivity.java). My code is a mess, but you'll figure it out!